# RestFul Web API return issue

Tags: rest

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Site getSite() {
    return (Site)siteFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(id));
    return Response.status(204).type("text/plain")
            .entity("Invalid Request!").build();
}
```

I am trying to return "Invalid Request" message if Site==NULL but there is error in return Response due to method. public Site getSite()

Can anyone suggest how to overcome That error code responce..

Comment: Your compiler didn't tell you anything about this one ? This code should not even compile !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error case is that Response...build() returns "Response".
Try building Site class with response.
ex

```
Response.status.(Status.OK).entity(site).build();
```

As side note: try to a void having two return statements,
Full example

```
@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public Response getSite() {
   Site site = (Site)siteFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(id));
   return (site == null)? 
                  Response.status(204).type("text/plain").
                  entity("Invalid Request!").build(): 
                  Response.status.(Status.OK).entity(site).build();
}
```